# How to use the same font in mathrm as for normal math?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, lyx

I write math homework in LyX on MacOS, using XeTex for non-Tex fonts in my document. I've noticed that `\mathrm` and operators like `\sin` and `\lim` use the same font as document font, and not the math font. Same goes for `\mathbf`. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help) `\mathrm` uses the declared up-shape math font. So it is absolutely not clear what you are asking for. Maybe you are searching for `\mathit`. But I don't think so. Maybe your font settings cause an automatic font replacement because of missing fonts. Maybe something completely different happens or you are expecting something unusual. Please show a minimal working example, so that we can reproduce the problem. Also explain, what exactly you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've noticed that `\mathrm` and operators like `\sin` and `\lim` use the same font as document [text] font, and not the math font. Same goes for `\mathbf`. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

You mention that you employ XeLaTeX to compile your document. Do you also employ the [unicode-math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package? If you do, you may achieve your formatting objectives by (a) replacing `\mathrm`, `\mathit`, and `\mathbf` with `\symup`, `\symit`, and `\symbf`, respectively and (b) issuing the instruction `\setoperatorfont\symup`.

---

[image]

```
%% compile with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{unicode-math} % for '\sym<xx>' and '\setoperatorfont' macros
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % or some other suitable text font
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setoperatorfont\symup

\begin{document}
x\textit{x}\textbf{x} % Times Roman text font
vs.\
$\mathrm{x}\mathit{x}\mathbf{x}$
vs.\
$\symup{x}\symit{x}\symbf{x}$ % Latin Modern math font

$\lim \sin \cos \ln$ % Latin Modern, not Times Roman
\end{document}
```